# Where are the Virtualbox command-line tools on macOS?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, docker, macos

I installed Virtualbox on my macOS Catalina 10.15.3. The GUI works perfectly. However, when I try to run a vm from the command line, the shell can't find the `VBoxManage` command. I need it for docker.

Where does the installer put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line tools for Oracle VirtualBox on macOS are usually kept in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ type -a VBoxManage
VBoxManage is /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage
```

These should be available in your interactive shell sessions if you have `/usr/local/bin` as part of your `$PATH`.